# ImportError from pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-import, importerror

I have a very simple python program that I am trying to run from PyCharm

```
from collections import Counter
import my_ds

my_list = my_ds.names

a = Counter(my_list)

print(a)
```

I am getting the following error.

```
    from collections import Counter
ImportError: cannot import name 'Counter'
```

However I am able to run this program using the same python interpreter from the commandline. What could be the reason for this?
I am using python 3.4

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you selected a python version newer or equal as 2.7. 
In fact, Counter is not available in python versions earlier than 2.7.
Go to settings, project, project interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

I am working also with pycharm latest 2018 version.
For me it was something else, i created by mistake or not (we can argue on that) a file named collections.py, once i created this file with this name pycharm was unable to import the real (one that comes with python 3.6 or anaconda) package. 
Only after renaming the file from collections.py to something else all worked.

I also filed this as a bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29254